# remove white space line from same named files in multiple subdirectories in unix

Tags: unix, removing-whitespace

I have multiple files ( > 1000) with same name in different subdirectories

dir1/out.txt

```
   # white row
    1 2 3 4 5
    3 3 4 5 6 
    4 1 4 5 8
    # white row
```

dir2/out.txt

```
 # white row  
    1 2 3 4 5
    3 3 4 5 6 

    4 1 4 5 8
    # white row
```

dir3/out.txt

```
# white row 
1 2 3 4 5
3 3 4 5 6 
4 1 4 5 8
# white row
```

I want to remove all white spaces (usually at heading row, tail row and in between rows.

Is there is quick way to do in Unix ? Apolozie for simple question.

Edit:

I am not trying to remove every space rather just whole lines that are white spaces

Comment: awk, sed: anything goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will find all the files named `out.txt` in subdirectories of present working directory and deletes while-space containing lines from each file.

```
find . -name "out.txt" -exec sed -i '/^$/d' '{}' \;
```

**Note**: You must own write permissions to modify these files.

Answer (score 1):

To remove just blank lines, use

```
sed -i '/^$/d' file
```

To remove blank-lines containing spaces use

```
sed -i '/^[[:blank:]]*/$' file
```

To remove all spaces from file, use

```
sed 's/ //g' file > file.new && /bin/mv file.new file
```

Thats a space char, if the white space might include tab char, then use

```
sed 's/[[:blank:]]//g' file
```

If you're using GNU sed on a linux, then you can do

```
sed -i 's/[[:blank:]]//g' file
```

And if you want to delete blank lines, then add

```
 sed -i 's/[[:blank:]]//g;/^$/d' file
```

---

You'd wrap all of this in a find cmd to get your file names like

```
 cd $baseDir ; find . -name '*.txt' -print | xargs sed -i 's/[[:blank:]]//g;/^$/d' {}
```

Use just the first part,

```
 find . -name '*.txt' -print
```

And adjust until you see the correct filename list appearing.

Then test the 2nd half, by forcing the find output to have just 1 test filename as output, i.e.

```
 find . -name 'myTestOut.txt' | xargs ...
```

I don't have an easy way to test this now, but this sort of question gets asked every day here on S.O., search by `[unix] [linux] [xargs] [sed]` .

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, When i implimented this is taking every white space in the file, I just wanted to remove intact / whole white space rows, not space that seperates column data

Comment: I misintrepreted your statement 'I  want to remove all white spaces...). That's why it really helps to include required output in your question. If you care to update your question with example output, I'll try to answer your question. Good luck.

Comment: thank you for the response, this may be helpful for others (who want to eliminate all spaces)...I have alternative answer, I think it is not good idea to steal your time more ..